# How to buy Ethereum outside the US?

Tags: go-ethereum, coinbase

I am trying to buy Ethereum and I live outside the US, Coinbase does not support my place!
Also, I'd like it to be simple, buying with PayPal or credit card, and not with Bank transfer such as Kraken

Comment: Can you buy Bitcoin where you are?

Answer (score 1):

https://localethereum.com/
You can find local sellers.

https://localbitcoins.com/ 
People who hold bitcoin may also hold ethereum you can try contacting people and make transaction in person.

Comment: Wants to use credit card.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy on eBay, which I have done.  The markup was huge, but I only wanted a few £ worth to see how it works, so it was worth paying for the convenience.